# Django username edit issue

Tags: django, django-authentication

I want to allow users to change their usernames, so I have a form:

```
class UserForm(models.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

In template, I have a greeting block, something like Hello, {{ request.user.username }}

When I submit a form with a username that already exists, it throws an error "User with this Userame already exists.", but in the greeting block I see Hello, username (where username is this one I have submitted).

What am I doing wrong? Anyone faced something similar?

Here is a view code:

```
@login_required
def persona_edit(request):

    form = PersonaForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user.persona)
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
    user_form = UserForm(request.POST or None, instance=user)

    if form.is_valid() and user_form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        user_form.save()
        messages.success(request, _(u'Profile updated'))
        return redirect('identity:dashboard')

    payload = {'form': form, 'user_form': user_form}
    return render(request, 'identity/persona_edit.html', payload)
```

Comment: Do you pass user instance to the form?

Comment: Django has a built-in form for changing user information in contrib.auth.forms > UserChangeForm

Comment: Thanks for responses, guys. I've found a reason. Issue appears when I send request.user as instance argument to a form. When I put there User.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk) it works fine. Seems like I have missed something in the documentation.

Comment: That's very odd. If you: >>> print type(request.user) it should be User. I'm not sure why request.user wouldn't be the same as a User instance...

Comment: @Brandon, I am wondered as well. Maybe that's something about Django "internal caching", no?

Comment: Possibly. I'd have to work through the code myself to see what's going on.

Comment: The reason for these odd things could be, that if you pass `request.user` as `instance` to the form, the form will work with a _reference_ to `request.user`, so when the form manipulates its instance `request.user` will be manipulated as well...